# Is there any programmatic reason not to use spaces in object names in MS Access 2013?

Tags: ms-access, naming-conventions, ms-access-2013, spaces

It seems to me that most MS Access developers strongly advocate for object names that strictly exclude the use of spaces.  I did not learn this until after the database I created was well-established, and subsequently I have spaces in almost every object name (tables, forms, queries, combo boxes, command buttons, and so on).  That said, aside from having to surround everything `[In Brackets]` when writing code, I have not encountered any problems or setbacks related to their use.  Is there some programmatic reason one should never use spaces that I am missing?

Comment: As long as you're conscientious about including the square brackets where required, I can't think of any harm caused by spaces in object identifiers.  But then you need square brackets.  Yuck!  :-)

Comment: I can't think of a functional downside either, but I do find the brackets make code more difficult to read since spaces jump out much more clearly, and searching through a long sql statement with multi-word query and field names can get exhausting. It really just forces an extra step when writing new code too. If I do need a space, I generally swap with an underscore so brackets are unnecessary, and they don't get confused with spaces.

Comment: Thank you both for the perspective!  Christopher, that certainly makes sense, and I have begun to experience that at times as I write more complicated queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some programmatic reason one should never use spaces that I am missing?

Not really. Many developers avoid such names (along with names that are [reserved words](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) in Access SQL) mainly for convenience, and it's still not a bad idea to do so when creating a new database. However, if your database is already created and deployed then you can simply carry on using `[square brackets]` to delimit object names.

(My guess is that the most vocal opponents of "names with spaces" developed their distaste for such names years ago when they *might* cause significant headaches if you happened to end up using a tool that mishandled them. However, most of the bugs have since been worked out; even Microsoft's "Northwind" sample database for Access uses table names that contain spaces.)

Answer (score 1):

Programmatic.  No.

But spaces can definitely cause problems and increase the cost of maintenance.   I have viewed it as a best practice sort of thing to not use spaces in database object names for a long time.

Comment: Could you provide an example of how using spaces would increase the cost of maintenance?

Comment: When just using pre-fab artifacts inside MS Access there are few issues.  But when you start delving into dynamic SQL, or having other systems reach into your access DB and do things.  Problems tend to crop up around objects with spaces or other odd characters in their names.

Comment: I can see how interacting with other systems less-equipped for dealing with spaces could lead to issues.  That's a good point -- thanks!